# Successfull Build in Android Studio still crashes on Device

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I'm pretty much a beginner still and I've tried to make an App to ease my work in the Lab. It's just some basic calculation. I want to make an App that is compatible to the most devices, in case its useful information. Even though the App seems to Build successfully, as soon as it starts on my Device it just crashes immediatelly. Files used are listed below. I tried all the hints Android Studio gave me with no result. App still crashed.

Would be very thankful for some hints and constructive feeback!

---

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com.e.concalc;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText protein_sp;
private EditText salt_sp;
private EditText protein_st;
private EditText salt_st;
private EditText volume_sp;

private TextView tv_resultH2O;
private TextView tv_resultSalt;
private TextView tv_resultProtein;

private Button button1;

public MainActivity(TextView tv_resultH2O, TextView tv_resultSalt, TextView tv_resultProtein, Button button1) {
    this.tv_resultH2O = tv_resultH2O;
    this.tv_resultSalt = tv_resultSalt;
    this.tv_resultProtein = tv_resultProtein;
    this.button1 = button1;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    protein_sp = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    protein_st = findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    salt_sp = findViewById(R.id.edit3);
    salt_st = findViewById(R.id.edit4);
    volume_sp = findViewById(R.id.edit5);



    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            makeCalculations();
        }
    });
}


private void makeCalculations() {
    double p_sp = Double.valueOf(protein_sp.getText().toString());
    double p_st = Double.valueOf(protein_st.getText().toString());
    double s_sp = Double.valueOf(salt_sp.getText().toString());
    double s_st = Double.valueOf(salt_st.getText().toString());
    double v_sp = Double.valueOf(volume_sp.getText().toString());

    double resultH2O;
    double resultSalt;
    double resultProtein;

    resultProtein = p_sp * v_sp / p_st;
    resultSalt = s_sp * v_sp / s_st;
    resultH2O = v_sp - resultProtein - resultSalt;



    tv_resultH2O.setText(Double.toString(resultH2O));
    tv_resultSalt.setText(Double.toString(resultSalt));
    tv_resultProtein.setText(Double.toString(resultProtein));
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml** - Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Protein1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.133"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.070" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Protein2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.77"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.070" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Salt1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.21" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Salt2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.21" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SampleVolume"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
    android:importantForAutofill="no" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/edit2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
    android:importantForAutofill="no" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/edit4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text4"
    android:importantForAutofill="no" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/edit3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text3"
    android:importantForAutofill="no" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text5"
    android:importantForAutofill="no" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.158"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:text="@string/button2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.745"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_resultH2O"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_resultSalt"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_resultProtein"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the constructor of MainActivity. Android does not work like that any UI element, like your text views need to be initialized by findViewById (which needs to exist in the layout you have specified in the setContentView)

Comment: @peco said the same and it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to **findViewById** the **button1**.So in `onCreate` method, before `button1.setOnClickListener`.... add this line:

```
button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Do the same to other views if you use them in java, not just to EditTexts.

Comment: Thank You very much! This really solved my Problem!

Answer (score 1):

Remove your custom constructor.

Activities must have a no-argument constructor that Android uses to create your class and when you define any override then the no-argument constructor is no longer automatically created for you in Java...

Comment: Thank you, after I removed the custom constructor it still crashed. I think your answer still contributed to my issue. Thank you!